# Плагин для вывода изображений и текста к ним?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужен плагин с помощью которого в админке можно указать изображения и подпись к ним (колличество изображений не фиксированно, можно в любой момент добавить новые), а потом в цикле вывести их в коде шаблона со своей версткой. Есть ли такие?

Answer (score 0):

Я использую плагин Smart Slider 3. Там как раз и изображение добавляется, и можно текст добавить. Многофункциональный плагин.